# Correct Way to Structure Models, Views and Serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following structure of Parent and Child models, where the child references the parent.

```py
class ParentModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class ChildModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        ParentModel, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ParentModel
        fields = (
            'name',
            'children',
        )


class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        models = ChildModel
        fields = (
            'name'
        )


class ParentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ParentSerializer
    queryset = ParentModel.objects.all()


class ChildViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ChildSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return ChildModel.objects.filter(created_by=user)
```

I would like for `ParentSerializer.children` to only include the `ChildModel` objects with `created_by` as `self.request.user`.

What is the correct way to filter `ParentSerializer.children` to the current user?

I am open to changing the models as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think you got a n+1 issue with your code.

When DRF will serialize ParentModel, accessing `current_parent.children.all()` will produce an SQL query for each parent.

To prevent this you can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) so:

```
class ParentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ParentSerializer
    queryset = ParentModel.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch("children"))
```

This will result in 2 SQL queries instead of N+1 (with N being the number of ParentModel row).

Additionnaly you can use `prefetch_related` to filter the related model:

```
class ParentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ParentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return ParentModel.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch("children", queryset=ChildrenModel.objects.filter(created_by=user)))
```

Which is what you are looking for I think.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, is there a better way of approaching this from the ground up?

Comment: You're welcome. To my knowledge this is a quite standard way of doing it. Prefetch is very useful to work with related entries when things are handle in Python (like serialization for example). It allows you to prefetch the same related entries with different filters thanks to the to_attr parameter for instance

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. In the case that I have a `Grandparent` in this context, would you approach it the same way?

Comment: Yes, you would be able to do use `prefetch_related` on the inner queryset too.